TPS63020 buck boost converter, how to use ENABLE pin?
I'm using a TPS63020 board connected to a small LIPO battery to power an e-ink display and driver. I'd like to use an ESP32 board to control the ENABLE pin (so I can shut down the e-ink display and driver, when the ESP32 board goes to sleep).
Can I connect the EN (enable) pin of the TPS63020 board directly to a pin on the ESP3 and configure the ESP32 pin as output? Then in code I can set the ESP32 pin to high or low so the e-ink display/driver doesn't consume battery when it's not needed. Should I add a resistor between the ESP32 pin and the EN pin of the TPS63020 board?
Thanks!


That is very low-quality documentation for an electronics product. It seems (with enough willingness to extrapolate from what is said and not said in the text) the enable pin is pulled high - but whether that's just the chip-internal pull up or some resistor going to any of the rails, impossible to tell. Anyway, you should try letting the Arduino output "float" (by setting the GPIO pin to a digital input role) for "ENABLED" and to pull it low (by setting the GPIO to be a digital output after setting its output state to low) for disabling the module. Good luck with this!

You can connect the EN (enable) pin of the TPS63020 board directly to a GPIO pin on the ESP32 and control it through your code. This setup allows you to enable or disable the power supply to the e-ink display and driver as needed.
